# Understanding basics concepts of measure concentration

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I've recently came across a Wiki article about [Concentration of Measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_of_measure).
At the very beginning of this article, in [general setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_of_measure#The_general_setting) we see the following:

> Let $(X,d,\mu)$ be a metric measure space, $\mu(X)=1$.

Then,

> $$\alpha(\epsilon):=\sup \{\mu(X / A_{\epsilon} )|\mu(A)>1/2\}$$

In this case $A_\epsilon$ is an extension of some set $A$. So my question is what does mean in this context that $\mu(A)>1/2$?

Does it essentially mean the requirement for $A$ is to occupy half of some volume?

Comment: Note that you have mistyped the first quote, it's not $\mu(x)=1$ but $\mu(X)=1$.

Comment: do you know what a *metric measure space* is?